# MySQL "Cannot allocate memory for the buffer pool" at 73% memory usage?

Tags: mysql, memory, memory-usage

I am hosting a WordPress website on a DigitalOcean droplet (1GB RAM). The website's MySQL database crashes occasionally, which causes the website to show "Error establishing database connection". Memory usage dropped around 2:40 am, indicating that this is when the database crashed. I checked the MySQL log file for that day, and the earliest entry was at 10:47 am. Here is the beginning of the log file:

```
2021-12-06T10:47:14.800977Z 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timest$
2021-12-06T10:47:14.806192Z 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 5.7.36-0ubuntu0.18.04.1) starting as process 2810 ...
2021-12-06T10:47:14.819674Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: PUNCH HOLE support available
2021-12-06T10:47:14.819711Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
2021-12-06T10:47:14.819716Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2021-12-06T10:47:14.819720Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: GCC builtin __atomic_thread_fence() is used for memory barrier
2021-12-06T10:47:14.819723Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2021-12-06T10:47:14.819727Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
2021-12-06T10:47:14.820551Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2021-12-06T10:47:14.823342Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using CPU crc32 instructions
2021-12-06T10:47:14.825847Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 128M, instances = 1, chunk size = 128M
2021-12-06T10:47:14.826246Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: mmap(137428992 bytes) failed; errno 12
2021-12-06T10:47:14.826258Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Cannot allocate memory for the buffer pool
2021-12-06T10:47:14.826262Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Plugin initialization aborted with error Generic error
2021-12-06T10:47:14.826270Z 0 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
2021-12-06T10:47:14.826274Z 0 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
2021-12-06T10:47:14.826278Z 0 [ERROR] Failed to initialize builtin plugins.
2021-12-06T10:47:14.826282Z 0 [ERROR] Aborting

2021-12-06T10:47:14.832237Z 0 [Note] Binlog end
2021-12-06T10:47:14.832297Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'CSV'
2021-12-06T10:47:14.832572Z 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete
```

Based on the log file, it appears MySQL is running out of memory. However, memory usage for the droplet was steady around 73%, until the database crash around 2:40 am, when it dropped down to 32%. It seems to have plenty of memory available, so why is it crashing?

EDIT As requested, here are the contents of my MySQL config files:

`/etc/mysql/conf.d/mysql.cnf`

```
[mysql]
```

`/etc/mysql/conf.d/mysqldump.cnf`

```
[mysqldump]
quick
quote-names
max_allowed_packet      = 16M
```

`/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf`

```
#
# The MySQL database server configuration file.
#
# You can copy this to one of:
# - "/etc/mysql/my.cnf" to set global options,
# - "~/.my.cnf" to set user-specific options.
#
# One can use all long options that the program supports.
# Run program with --help to get a list of available options and with
# --print-defaults to see which it would actually understand and use.
#
# For explanations see
# http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/server-system-variables.html

# This will be passed to all mysql clients
# It has been reported that passwords should be enclosed with ticks/quotes
# escpecially if they contain "#" chars...
# Remember to edit /etc/mysql/debian.cnf when changing the socket location.

# Here is entries for some specific programs
# The following values assume you have at least 32M ram

[mysqld_safe]
socket          = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
nice            = 0

[mysqld]
#
# * Basic Settings
#
user            = mysql
pid-file        = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
socket          = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
port            = 3306
basedir         = /usr
datadir         = /var/lib/mysql
tmpdir          = /tmp
lc-messages-dir = /usr/share/mysql
skip-external-locking
#
# Instead of skip-networking the default is now to listen only on
# localhost which is more compatible and is not less secure.
bind-address            = 127.0.0.1
#
# * Fine Tuning
#
key_buffer_size         = 16M
max_allowed_packet      = 16M
thread_stack            = 192K
thread_cache_size       = 8
# This replaces the startup script and checks MyISAM tables if needed
# the first time they are touched
myisam-recover-options  = BACKUP
#max_connections        = 100
#table_open_cache       = 64
#thread_concurrency     = 10
#
# * Query Cache Configuration
#
query_cache_limit       = 1M
query_cache_size        = 16M
#
# * Logging and Replication
#
# Both location gets rotated by the cronjob.
# Be aware that this log type is a performance killer.
# As of 5.1 you can enable the log at runtime!
#general_log_file        = /var/log/mysql/mysql.log
#general_log             = 1
#
# Error log - should be very few entries.
#
log_error = /var/log/mysql/error.log
#
# Here you can see queries with especially long duration
#slow_query_log         = 1
#slow_query_log_file    = /var/log/mysql/mysql-slow.log
#long_query_time = 2
#log-queries-not-using-indexes
#
# The following can be used as easy to replay backup logs or for replication.
# note: if you are setting up a replication slave, see README.Debian about
#       other settings you may need to change.
#server-id              = 1
#log_bin                        = /var/log/mysql/mysql-bin.log
expire_logs_days        = 10
max_binlog_size   = 100M
#binlog_do_db           = include_database_name
#binlog_ignore_db       = include_database_name
#
# * InnoDB
#
# InnoDB is enabled by default with a 10MB datafile in /var/lib/mysql/.
# Read the manual for more InnoDB related options. There are many!
#
# * Security Features
#
# Read the manual, too, if you want chroot!
# chroot = /var/lib/mysql/
#
# For generating SSL certificates I recommend the OpenSSL GUI "tinyca".
#
# ssl-ca=/etc/mysql/cacert.pem
# ssl-cert=/etc/mysql/server-cert.pem
# ssl-key=/etc/mysql/server-key.pem
```

`/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld_safe_syslog.cnf`

```
[mysqld_safe]
syslog
```

Comment: you should have some variables setting in /etc/my.cnf.d/server.cnf related to memory and/or innodb that do not fit with your database size or memory. can you show us these variables and your database size ?

Comment: @dominix There is no /etc/my.cnf.d/server.cnf directory or file. The closest thing I can find is /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf. The server is running Ubuntu 18.04, if that helps.

Comment: Can you add a longer snippet of the log file to the question? This log file looks like the MySQL server is just starting up, which doesn't match your description.

Comment: @dominix The database size is 43.5 MB.

Comment: @TeroKilkanen According to memory usage history, it appears the database crashed around 2:40 am. However, the log file for that day has no entries before 10:47 am. This is the closest I could get to the time of the database crash. I will expand my question to include all entries from the start of the log file.

Comment: Did you check the rotated log files?

Comment: @TeroKilkanen I have updated the wording in my question, hopefully it is clearer now.

Comment: @TeroKilkanen You mean the compressed log files in /var/log/mysql? Yes, I decompressed them and read them.

Comment: Does `/var/log/kern.log` have anything around the time of crash?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/132261/discussion-between-bumbleshoot-and-tero-kilkanen).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After reviewing kernel log in the chat, the reason for MySQL crash was out of memory situation.

```
Dec 6 02:47:13  kernel: [341799.228400] Out of memory: Kill process 23566 (mysqld) score 197 or sacrifice child
Dec 6 02:47:13  kernel: [341799.229866] Killed process 23566 (mysqld) total-vm:1168576kB, anon-rss:198536kB, file-rss:0kB, shmem-rss:0kB
```

During that time there were lots of Apache2 processes active. This means that increasing traffic causes increased memory consumption. As a result, kernel decided to kill MySQL to free up memory.

One can run `mysqltuner` to analyse MySQL configuration. It gives recommendations, which can help to reduce MySQL memory consumption.

However, increasing traffic can still cause same problems. Therefore more sustainable solution is to increase memory available for the droplet.

Comment: I just checked Google Analytics for this website, and there was only one page view on December 6 (the website went down on December 6 between 2:40-2:50 am). This doesn't seem to be matching up with what you saw in the kernel log. Any idea why?

Comment: Google Analytics only shows traffic from web browsers that execute the Google Analytics JS code. In addition, the internet has lots of bot traffic. You can see that traffic in your web server\s access.log

Comment: Okay, makes sense. Must have been a lot of bot traffic all at once to overwhelm a server that was consistently using only 73% memory? Do you think it was a DDoS attack? Is there some way to block this bot traffic in the future?

Answer (score 1):

1GB of RAM is *very tiny* these days.  The server *might* survive if you set `innodb_buffer_pool_size = 50M`.  Recommendations for some percentage of RAM do not apply for such a small RAM size.

There is a risk that 50M will be too small.  Please provide your `my.cnf` so we can look for other settings to shrink.  Some likely ones:

```
max_connections = 10
key_buffer_size = 10M
temp_table_size = 10M
max_heap_table_size = 10M
table_open_cache = 100

query_cache_size = 0
max_allowed_packet = 8M
key_buffer_size = 10M
max_connections = 10
```

Yes, MySQL/MariaDB will run in a tiny machine, but tuning is necessary.

If Apache is running on the same server, lower its MaxRequestWorkers to 10.  And check the configuration of anything else running in the same [virtual] server.